# Flask Not Receiving Data from HTTP POST

Tags: api, flask

I'm working on my first POST method route in my API.  For some reason when I pass variables to it via url http://test.com/test?stuff=wee, Flask throws errors like stuff didn't make it through.

Code:

```
@app.route('/test', methods = ['POST'])
def testindex():

    stuff = request.args.get('stuff')

    response_message = "success"
    response_data = stuff
    errors = "None"
    response = {
        'response message' : response_message,
        'response data': response_data,
        'errors' : errors
    }

    js = json.dumps(response)
    resp = Response(js, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
    return resp
```

cURL:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"stuff":"wee"}' http://test.com/test?stuff=wee
```

response:

```
{"errors": "None", "response data": null, "response message": "success"}
```

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.args.get` is for getting parameters from GET. You'll want `request.form`.

Comment: changed it to var =request.get_json().get('stuff', ''), works great.  Thanks.